# Can I override "force:hasRecordId" on child Aura component

Tags: javascript, aura

I have a child Aura component that implements the "force:hasRecordId" interface.

I want to use a recordId passed into the child component by a parent Aura component. **I do not want the child component to use the recordId of the page that the components are placed on.**

Looking at the attached photos, when the child component accesses the recordId variable using `component.get("v.recordId")` I want it to be "exampleId"

Child:
[image]

Parent:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo in your code:

- For passing data from parent to child using an attribute we need to
  use syntax - `{!v.exampleId}`

I tried this scenario and below is the working code for the same.

**Parent Markup :**
Here , we declare an attribute named `exampleId` of type String and pass to the child component.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
  
  <aura:attribute  name="exampleId" type="String" default="abc"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" description="Handler for valueInit event fired when the component has been initialised"/>

 
  <c:attributeChild recordId="{!v.exampleId}"></c:attributeChild>
</aura:component>
```

**Child Markup:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global">
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

  <div>
    Record Id in child : {!v.recordId}
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

In the UI you would see value of `exampleId` :
[image]

But I would advise you to rename it with something else since it will create confusion.